# In hue we are not able to find table

Tags: hive, hue

Client created a table in hue under some db and that table is not reflecting in hue. But we are able to see that table in Hive but not in hue browser.
Please someone can help me on this
Thanks.

Comment: Have you done analyze table ? Also, click on the refresh database option in hue so hue updates its client metadata.

Comment: Yes i did analyze the table and also refresh the database from hue browser. Still issue didn't resolve

Comment: Even form the database and tables have inuff permissions

Comment: Could you please help it is impacting to daily job from our client side

Comment: Its very difficult to guess - how many tables you have in that schema ? we noticed, if number of tables is more than 5000, hue doesnt show them.

Comment: Yes it is more then 5000 tables. So how can it be solve

Comment: cant do much there. Hue cant display more than 5000 objects. You need to assume its there and you can see using show create table etc. I feel like remove some unwanted objects or split objects into multiple schemas.

Comment: So I tried to created a table that table was reflecting in both hue and hive cli. But when client is trying to create table that table is not reflecting in hue

Comment: As i said before, its hue display problem/bug. You can try clear up or move them to another schema.

Comment: Can we increase the limitation from 5000 to 8000

Comment: Yes, there is a unofficial way to increase. i am mentioning in below answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer client approved this suggestion.

Comment: I have one more question. In Hive i created a internal table and dropped that table for just poc so I tried to recover that table from trash location i moved that that table from trash to original hdfs location but when I checked In Hive i recreated that table again and then I check there was no data inside. Could you please suggest how to recover a dropped table

Comment: M happy the solution worked.

Comment: Pls create an external table on top of that original location. You should be able to see the data.

Comment: Not able to see created external table on top of it

Comment: Please help out again bro

Comment: Could you please tell me the procedure after dropping the internal table what should we do.

Comment: Could you pls create a new issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

a. distribute the tables in multiple DBs (recommended).
b. manually adjust the 'rows' limit in dbms.py as shown in below. Change it from 5000 to 8000.
Restart hue after the change.
Sample from /usr/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/dbms.py below:

```
-----------------
if handle:
result = self.fetch(handle, rows=8000) --> This value needs to be changed to 8000.
self.close(handle)
return [name for table in result.rows() for name in table]
else:
return []
```

Please note, since you are customizing this file, you need to apply this change after every hive upgrade and hue performance can be impacted because of this.